# How to avoid printing this WARN message in JBoss

Tags: jboss

My logs are getting hammered by below log message in JBOSS 7. Can you anyone suggest how to stop this log message.

```
2018-02-28 13:37:13,618 WARN  [com.arjuna.ats.arjuna] (default-threads - 48) ARJUNA012141: Multiple last resources have been added to the current transaction. This is transactionally unsafe and should not be relied upon. Current resource is LastResourceRecord(XAOnePhaseResource(LocalXAResourceImpl@5d70439b[connectionListener=653eac5d connectionManager=7f6856e8 warned=false currentXid=null productName=MySQL productVersion=10.2.13-MariaDB-log jndiName=java:/jdbc/db_jndi]))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your standalone.xml file, in the logging section, add something like this under the appropriate handler element:

```
<filter>
        <not>
            <match pattern="ARJUNA012141"/>
        </not>
</filter>
```

Of course, you should add these lines using the jboss-cli utility. Did you know that changes to logging don't require a server restart, but will be picked up at the defined refresh interval?